# Close all disclosures programmatically with HeadlessUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, headless-ui

I have a list of `<Disclosure>` (about 10) that are set with `defaultOpen` when the page loads.

I would like to programmatically close the disclosures with the click of a button. For example a button reads `close all` and when clicked the disclosures close.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(true)

const close = () => {setOpen(false)}

<button onClick={close}>Close All</button>

<Disclosure defaultOpen>
  <Disclosure.Button>Open/Close</Disclosure.Button>
  <Disclosure.Panel>
    <p>disclosure1</p>
  </Disclosure.Panel>
</Disclosure>

<Disclosure defaultOpen>
  <Disclosure.Button>Open/Close</Disclosure.Button>
  <Disclosure.Panel>
    <p>disclosure2</p>
  </Disclosure.Panel>
</Disclosure>

<Disclosure defaultOpen>
  <Disclosure.Button>Open/Close</Disclosure.Button>
  <Disclosure.Panel>
    <p>disclosure3</p>
  </Disclosure.Panel>
</Disclosure>
```

Is there a way to do this? from the docs I have found:

```
      <Disclosure.Panel>
        {({ close }) => (
          <button
            onClick={async () => {
              await fetch('/accept-terms', { method: 'POST' })
              close()
            }}
          >
            Read and accept
          </button>
        )}
      </Disclosure.Panel>
```

But I can't find anything else for closing them without manually clicking the `<Disclosure.Button/>`

Comment: Hi, is there any hope on this?